# ThawAccount Error: Invalid account state for operation

Tags: account, typescript

When I perform a transaction I get an error and log entries:
'Program log: Instruction: ThawAccount',
'Program log: Error: Invalid account state for operation',

How to check whether an account is frozen or not using typescript (get state account)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using typescript, you can fetch the account with `@solana/spl-token` and check to see if it's frozen directly:

```
import { getAccount } from '@solana/spl-token';
const accountInfo = await getAccount(connection, tokenAccountAddress);
console.log(accountInfo.isFrozen);
```

Adapted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/4ff1f6fe85ca8a931e59972493b491a7469c0477/token/js/test/e2e-2022/defaultAccountState.test.ts#L95-L106